# php constructor does not seems to work

Tags: php, mysqli, php-mysqlidb

I have this class:

```
class template {

    private $_db;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->_db = \MysqliDb::getInstance();
    }


    public function get(){

        return $this->_db->rawQuery("SHOW COLUMNS FROM rank LIKE 'view_template'");
    }
}
```

But, when I execute the method `get`, I get this error message:

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function rawQuery() on a non-object in {dir/to/my/file} on line 50
```

Line 50 is `return $this->_db->rawQuery("SHOW COLUMNS FROM rank LIKE 'view_template'");`

The weird thing is that it works fine if I move the code from `__construct` to the `get` method, like this:

```
class template {

    private $_db;

    public function get(){

        $this->_db = \MysqliDb::getInstance();
        return $this->_db->rawQuery("SHOW COLUMNS FROM rank LIKE 'view_template'");
    }
}
```

What can be wrong in this case?

Comment: It sounds like the instance isn't actually available when you instantiate the `template` class, but it is later on when you call get.

Comment: Suppose you call the method statically, without instantiating the class, show how you call get() method

Comment: @alzee @Mikhail Thanks, you are right. I was initializating the class template, then the class Mysqlidb and then executing the `get` method so you were completly right about the moment when is available and the issue was related to the way I was calling the classes and methods.

Comment: In the constructor, if the result of getinstance is invalid, you should throw an exception.  Not just here, but in any other classes like this that you write.  It'll make it easier to track down problems like this.

Comment: Good advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think

> \MysqliDb::getInstance()

; isn't returning a valid object at the time when the construct is called, this is why you are getting the error.

You could check the object returned in the construct to see if a valid object is returned before calling the get method

> public function __construct(){ $this->_db = \MysqliDb::getInstance();
>   var_dump( $this->_db); }

Comment: Didn't solve the issue directly, but you were completely right in your statement. =)

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, i knew it won't solve the problem, but it would help you identify the issue,